# When Keyboard Present, Choose What Causes View To Slide Up

Tags: swift, user-interface, uikit

I have a tableView with a textField within row 0 and textView within row 3. My tableview currently slides up every time when the keyboard is present. When the tableView slides up, you can't see the textField within row 0. How do I disable this for row 0 and just keep for row 3? I tried using using Protocol & Delegates to try to encapsulate the function only for row 3, but that doesn't work.

[image]
    class CreateEditItemController: UIViewController, CreateItemDescriptionCellDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func handleKeyboardShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            //self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= 200
        }
    }
}

func handleKeyboardHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    ...
    case 3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CreateItemDescriptionCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateItemDescriptionCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    default:
        return tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
     }
   }
 }


protocol CreateItemDescriptionCellDelegate: class {
    func handleKeyboardShow(notification: NSNotification)
    func handleKeyboardHide(notification: NSNotification)
}

class CreateItemDescriptionCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
//IBOUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var notesTextView: UITextView!
weak var delegate: CreateItemDescriptionCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    notesTextView.delegate = self

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func handleKeyboardShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    delegate?.handleKeyboardShow(notification: notification)
}

@objc func handleKeyboardHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    delegate?.handleKeyboardHide(notification: notification)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible after some mathematics but i would recommend using a third party pod for this instead of doing this manually on evert controller.

Add this to your pod file:

```
# IQKeyboardManager: Codeless drop-in universal library allows to prevent issues of keyboard sliding up
# https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

For further detail and documentation view: 
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

The only line you would have to write would be :

```
// Enabling IQKeyboardManager
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
```

in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

This will solve all your problems and you wont have to calculate the frames or anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few routes you can go down, but for simplicities sake, there are a few libraries you can use to get all the calculations down for you and you don't need to worry about it.

One I use all the time is:

`TPKeyboardAvoiding` - https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

`IQKeyboardManagerSwift` - https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

And many others.